# Windows Update not working under XP Pro SP3

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

Since last 2 weeks Windows Update is not working at all. No "Updates are available" messages. When I run Microsoft Update, it opens IE 8. Doesn't matter if I select Express or Custom, it is stuck for hours at "Checking for the latest updates for your computer". I have tried repeatedly at different times of the day.

[image: Windows Update]

Automatic Updates enabled and service is running. Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) is running. I have tried setting all services to default like BlackViper says for XP Professional SP3 and all seem to be fine.

I have run all Microsoft FixIts I could find including http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058 and also performed all manual repair steps on that page. All successful but no change.

Microsoft Security Essentials is getting updated properly but earlier I was getting updates for it via Windows Update also. Scanned for viruses, trojans and rootkits many times with many different programs. Nothing detected so far and I believe system is clean.

I need Windows XP on this system so what can I try next to fix Windows Update?

Comment: Is it possible there are no updates?

Comment: @CharlieRB - Very possible.  As far as I am aware MSE is only updated through `Windows Update` on `Windows 7` and `Windows Vista`.

Comment: @CharlieRB - Thanks, but as long as WU was working properly the Express & Custom scans used to get over in less than a minute and it would show me if there were relevant updates or none at all. Now it's just stuck indefinitely in the scan process.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks, but I am using MS Update, not WU. There *is* a difference. Once the [MSU ActiveX control](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MIba3.png) is installed it replaces the WU one and offers definitions updates for MSE too. It's like the [MSU option](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EuemT.jpg) that programs like Office add to Windows 7. Selecting it starts giving you updates for MS products other than just Windows.

Comment: Check this out to see if it helps; [XP Pro Windows Update Hangs at "Checking for the latest updates for your computer..."](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=224668)

Comment: @CharlieRB: Thanks, but those are just a few steps whereas I have done all manual repair steps mentioned in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on a fresh install of WinXP Pro SP3.  This thread is what fixed it for me:

http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/163751-windows-update-trouble/

Bottom line was installing this cumulative update took care of an issue that MS had created earlier that was causing the Windows Update to take forever:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40390